# How to create reusable vue components in laravel nova?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

How I can do **reusable** components in Laravel Nova with **Vue**? I read the documentation, but I can't find a example of that.
I want to use the same vue component in one or more nova components.It's possible accomplish that  following the patterns from the laravel nova? Or just doing workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you make the Vue component in '/resources/js/components/ReusableComponent.vue' and then import it in each one of your tools? Alternatively, you could create a private/public git repository which stores your reusable components and import it into each tool.

E.g.

- resources

  - js

    - components

      - ReusableComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</template>
```

- nova-components

  - NovaTool

    - resources

      - js

        - components

          - MyToolsComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <reusable-component />
</template>

<script>
import ResuableComponent from '../../../../../resources/js/components/ReusableComponent.vue';

export default {
    components: { ReusableComponent },
};
</script>
```

If you want to publish these tools for composer you will have to create a NPM lib which you can include into the tool so you can distribute it with it.